# rand() generating same number upon compilation

Tags: c++, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the Right Way to use the rand() Function in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117292/whats-the-right-way-to-use-the-rand-function-in-c)

I've been learning how to use the rand() function and I wrote a small guessing game in C++ as seen bellow, but the problem is, no matter how many times I compile the programs the generated number is the same -> 41

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = rand()%100;
    int y=0;
    cout << "Ghiceste numarul!" << endl;
    cin >> y;

    while(y != x) {

         if(y > x) {
            cout << "Numarul tau este prea mare! Incearca un numar mai mic!" << endl;
            cin >> y;
          }

             if(y < x) {
                 cout << "Numarul tau este prea mic!" << endl;
                 cin >> y;
               }

      if (y == x) {
      cout << "FELICITARI, AI GHICIT NUMARUL!\n";
      return 0;
      }
    }
}
```

I also tried to change the max value of rand() and it did change as long as I put it < 41.

Any ideas? I don't have a *clue* as to why this is happening. I am using CodeBlocks IDE and I tried rebuilding (CTRL+F11)

Answer (score 18):

Try adding

```
srand(time(0));
```

at the beginning of `main`.

Comment: Do this, but be aware you only need to do it once at the beginning of your program. Don't do it every time you call `rand()`.

Comment: And be aware of the caveat: If you run your program more than once per second, it will re-use random seeds (and give you the same numbers every time you run the program until a second passes).

Comment: Both good points. Be sure to check out the SO post referenced in tenfour's comment to your question.

Answer (score 7):

You should try first to initialize a seed for the rand() function as follows:

```
srand (time(NULL))
```

at the beginning of `main`. Make sure to include the time.h in the header

```
#include <time.h>
```

or

```
#include <ctime>
```

Answer (score 2):

it's probably using the same seed each time for the random number generator. if you [set the seed of the random number generator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/srand/) each time to a different value, you will get different numbers. according to the docs:

> In order to generate random-like numbers, srand is usually initialized
>   to some distinctive value, like those related with the execution time.
>   For example, the value returned by the function time (declared in
>   header ) is different each second, which is distinctive enough
>   for most randoming needs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a seed to the rand() function which will be different each time the program is run (e.g. timestamp).  Generally speaking, generating truly random numbers isn't possible but you can get a pseudo-random.

Answer (score 0):

You need to seed the rand function with srand() at the beginning of `main`, typically using time(); function

Answer (score 0):

The random number generator is being seeded with the same default state on each run of your program.

In order to get different results on each run, you need to seed the random number generator in your program by calling `srand()` and passing in a new seed. It's common to use the return value of `time(NULL)` as the seed, as that will guarantee that you get a different seed on different runs of you program.

So add the following at the beginning of `main`:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```