# rand() Random Number Generation C++

Tags: c++, random

I am trying to generate pseudo random ints using the `rand()` function. It works, but my problem is that it is always "selecting" the same name for the int. (In this case, it is 41. I think if you put the `rand()` in the while loop of main it is 85 or something.)

Is there a way to fix this? Here is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int guess;
    int danse = rand() % 101;

    using namespace std;

    void more(){
    cout << "The number that you need to guess is higher!";

    return;
    }

    void lower(){
    cout << "The number that you need to guess is lower!";

    return;
    }

    int main(){
    while(1){
    cout << "\nGuess a number 0-100: ";
    cin >> guess;

    if (guess > danse){
        lower();
}
    if (guess < danse){
        more();
}

    if (guess == 101){
        break;
}

    if (guess == danse){
        cout << "\nYOU GUESSED IT. ARE YOU A WIZARD?! BECAUSE THAT IS PRETTY NEAT.";
        break;
}
    }
    }
```

Just a few side notes: Please don't try and tell me things I already know, like, explaining why I am using void functions, with return. Please, also do not try to convince me that using namespace std; is the "bad" way to do it. I understand that there are other ways of doing it. I choose not to.

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of :http://stackoverflow.com/q/9421463/1870232

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to seed the random number generator by calling [srand](http://linux.die.net/man/3/srand) once before using `rand`.  The current time is a cheap and easy way to choose a seed that varies between runs of your program.

```
int danse;

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    danse = rand() % 101;
```

Answer (score 2):

`rand()` generates a pseudo-random sequence, starting at a given
seed.  For any specified seed, all of the following values will
be the same.  By default, the seed is 1.

In order to get differnt values each time you run the program,
you need to seed the generator (using `srand()`) with something
that seems random from the user's point of view.  The best
solution on a Unix machine, is to read enough bytes from
`"/dev/random"` to create an `int`, and use that.  On other
systems, you'll have to find something else; `time( NULL )` is
the classic solution, but of course, if the program is started
several times in the same second (even on different machines),
it will output the same sequence.  Hashing in additional values,
like the process id, the ip address of the machine, or such,
will improve things considerably.

And finally: some generators will return the seed as the first
value.  Which is very predictable, especially if you just use
`time( NULL )`.  You probably want to generate a couple of
random values which you throw away before you start actually
using them.

Answer (score 1):

You are not seeing the random number generator, so it will give you the exact same set of "random" numbers each time you run your application (this can be useful for debugging).  To fix it, modify your main to look like this:

```
int danse = 0;
int main()
{
    std::srand(std::time(0)); // seed the random number generator
    danse = rand() % 101;
    // rest of your main
}
```

Comment: That won't work, because he'll have already initialized `danse` before hand.

Comment: Ah, didn't see him doing that in the declaration ... I'll add that to the example code.