# C++ Rand Function error

Tags: c++, random

I'm trying to make a text based Role playing game and I'm currently implementing the diceroll function:

```
int diceRoll(){
int n;
srand(time(0));
n = rand() % 4;
return n;
}
int main()
{
    int RandNum = diceRoll();
    cout<< "   Randomly generated number: " + RandNum;
    return 0;
}
```

Yet it outputs this:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1117317/962089. Since it was deleted, `const char (&)[N] + int` does not as you intend it to work.

Comment: Try using << instead of + when you output RandNum to cout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try: `cout << "Randomly generated number: " << RandNum;`

Comment: Thanks! Working perfectly fine now

Answer (score 4):

You're actually adding the number to the string... which doesn't do what you think it does. It in fact calcualtes and address offset from the string which I'm guessing is why you added some spaces at the beginning of it. You probably wanted the stream insertion operator, `<<`:

```
cout<< "   Randomly generated number: " << RandNum;
```

Additionally, it's a bad idea to call `srand()` inside your random number generator. Why? Because if you call it a bunch of times quickly `time()` might return the same value each time, causing `rand()` to be seeded with the same value every time and hence giving the same result (aka not very random). You should call `srand()` once at the beginning of your program, in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using rand() and modulus generally. It's a bad habit. Instead, use `<random>`:
[http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/)
Or just google "c++ random header usage" or something simillar.

Comment: cplusplus.com is bad and you should feel bad